# What is the dividend if yield is 3.04?

Tags: stocks, dividends

If you look at [Ambev stock on NYSE](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3AABEV&ei=IhYeWfHpFsbEjAGhgYvoDg) the value for `Div/yield` is     `-/3.04`.

Why is the dividend a dash `-`?

If you look at [Chevron on NYSE](https://www.google.com/finance?q=NYSE%3ACVX&ei=0xceWZiMI8Sy2Aar9Iv4BQ) `Div/yield` says `1.08/4.11` which makes sense, a dividend of `$1.08` per stock and yield of `4.11%`.

Comment: Can it be as simple as "$5.50 * 3.04% = $0.1672"?

Comment: @RonJohn Yes, that's how it works, but why is there a dash written in Google Finance? Does it have a meaning?

Comment: It looks like google's algo is having trouble with the inconsistency of the dividend payments.  And separately, you calculate the yield not the dividend.  You take either the trailing dividend payments or the projected dividend payments to derive a yield, not the other way around.

Comment: Just an fyi yahoo and finviz show .09/1.64%   Which seems to be based off of the first dividend this year at .021. Although 4 dividends at .021 only adds up to .084 not .09.   Google seems to be doing the math based on the last 4 dividends which are inconsistent. (0.021, 0.067, 0.051, 0.039)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the hover text of the said screen;

> Latest dividend/dividend yield
>
> Latest dividend is dividend per share paid to shareholders in the most
>   recent quarter. Dividend yield is the value of the latest dividend,
>   multiplied by the number of times dividends are typically paid per
>   year, divided by the stock price.

So for Ambev looks like the dividend is inconsistantly paid and not paid every quarter.